# Eigenvalues and eigenspaces of differential operator on finitely generated vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions, differential-operators

Let $V$ be a vector space generated by functions $e^{\lambda_1x},\dots, e^{\lambda_nx}$, where $\lambda_1, \dots,\lambda_n$ are pairwise distinct numbers. Define the differential operator $$\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}:V\to V.$$
Find the eigenvalues and eigenspaces of this operator.

**My approach:** I know how to show that $e^{\lambda_1x},\dots, e^{\lambda_nx}$ are linearly independent functions. Hence they will be a basis for $V$. It's easy to show that the matrix of this operator in this basis is the following:  $$\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda^2_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \lambda^2_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 &  \cdots & \lambda^2_n \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then it follows easily that eigenvalues are $\{\lambda^2_1,\dots, \lambda^2_n\}$.

Let's try to find eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda^2_k$, i.e. $V_{\lambda^2_k}:=\ker(\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}-\lambda^2_k\cdot \text{id})$

If $f\in V_{\lambda^2_k}$ then $\dfrac{d^2f}{dx^2}-\lambda^2_kf=0$. Suppose $f=\beta_1e^{\lambda_1 x}+\dots_+\beta_ne^{\lambda_n x}$ and since those exponents are basis it means that: $\beta_j\lambda_j^2-\beta_j\lambda_k^2=0$ for $j=1,\dots,n$.  It implies that $\beta_j(\lambda_j+\lambda_k)=0$. Then I stuck here.

But after some moment I've realized that $\dim V_{\lambda^2_k} \leq$ multiplicity of $\lambda^2_k$ which is 1. Then I have checked that $\langle e^{\lambda_k x}\rangle\subseteq V_{\lambda^2_k}$  which imples that $\dim V_{\lambda^2_k}=1$ and $V_{\lambda^2_k}=\langle e^{\lambda_k x}\rangle$.

I am sure that this is correct solution but one moments which confuses is that I was not able to deduce it from those above equations.

Can anyone show how to deduce it from those equations?

Comment: Base on your argument, you have either $\lambda_j = \lambda_k$ or $-\lambda_k$. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from your equation $$\beta_j (\lambda_j + \lambda_k) = 0$$ that for each $j \neq k$ we have $\beta_j = 0$ or $\lambda_k = -\lambda_j$.

- If the former is true for all $j \neq k$, then we have computed that the eigenspace $V_{\lambda_k^2}$ is spanned by $e^{\lambda_k x}$.
- On the other hand, if the latter is true for some $j \neq k$ (by hypothesis it can only be true for one $j$), then we have computer that the eigenspace $V_{\lambda_k^2}$ is spanned by $e^{\lambda_k x}$ and $e^{\lambda_j x} = e^{-\lambda_k x}$.

In particular, this shows that the multiplicity of $\lambda_k^2$ (and the dimension of $V_{\lambda_k^2}$) need not be $1$, and indeed that it is not precisely when $\lambda_j = -\lambda_k$ for some $j \neq k$.

Comment: I have realized that my argument is wrong. Multiplicity of $\lambda_k^2$ may not be 1, right? So it means that my reasoning is wrong!

Comment: Correct---my answer shows that using the equation $\beta_j (\lambda_j + \lambda_k)$ you derived that the multiplicity of $\lambda_k^2$ can be $1$ or $2$.

Comment: Btw, i cannot understand the second point of your answer. How did you get that in this case eigenspace is spanned by those two vectors? Could you give more details, please,

Comment: I guess that I got. Sorry for stupid question. In the second such $j$ is unique because all lambda's are pairwise distinct, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly: Put another way, any nonnegative number has at most $2$ square roots.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I am very thankful! :)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful.